# Possible to force glide to load images synchronously if already in cache?

Tags: android, android-glide

### Background info

The current Android application that I am working on has some images sitting inside some `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

The problem is that the same `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` also contains other formatted data - and when those change `notifyDataSetChanged` must be called even when the image itself has stayed the same.

The current code that handles image loading inside the `RecyclerView` is the following (note that it is pseudocode).

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>
{
    // more code here

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        // more code here

        loadMyImage(holder.picture, myLink);
    }

    public void loadMyImage(AppCompatImageView picture, Uri myLink)
    {
        picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);

        Glide.with(context).load(myLink).into(picture); // asynchronous load
    }
}
```

### My problem

The problem is that this causes a slight but very noticeable flickering between `R.drawable.placeholder` and `myLink`.

### My attempt

Now there are 2 things that I have come up with at this point in time to solve this issue.

1) Try to place the views into different view holders by redoing the layout and also redoing the underlying code.
[This is not an option due to the sheer amount of spaghetti and legacy code that forms the basis of this project]

2) Try and change the line `Glide.with(context).load(myLink).into(picture); // asynchronous load` into one that forces a synchronous load if already in cache.
[Theoretically removing the flicker and only adding nominal delay - since it is already in cache anyways]

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>
{
    // more code here

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        // more code here

        loadMyImage(holder.picture, myLink);
    }

    public void loadMyImage(AppCompatImageView picture, Uri myLink)
    {
        picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);

        if (inCache(myLink))
        {
            Glide.with(context).load(myLink).into(picture).synchronously();
        }
        else
        {
            Glide.with(context).load(myLink).into(picture).asynchronously();
        }
    }
}
```